# What do service(s)/process(es) do I need to ensure are running for Cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin, services

Cygwin doesn't seem to be running on my machine (never used it before, although I have installed it!). What services or processes do I need to start so it can run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### There is no "it" to run.

Cygwin isn't a distinct runnable entity in its own right.  The tools and programs *that use Cygwin*, from the Cygwin port of `bash` to the Cygwin port of `awk`, are.  They, presuming that you have your path and whatnot configured correctly, *just run* when you decide to invoke them.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this for me, I'm new to the whole emulating Unix on Windows thing =)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easist to uninstall it, download the latest copy and install that.

The installer should (presumably) ensure essential services or prerequisites are installed (and running).  There are no prerequisites I can find on their website.